# URL redirection rule for .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need some permanent (301) redirection rule to redirect multiple versions of documents to new location.

For example I have:

```
www.domain.com/about/about.html
www.domain.com/about/about.pdf
www.domain.com/about/about.doc
www.domain.com/about/about.rtf
www.domain.com/about/about.txt
```

and I need to redirect all of them to:

```
www.domain.com/about
```

Also I have URLs like this:

```
www.domain.com/privacy_policy/privacy_policy.html
www.domain.com/privacy_policy/privacy_policy.pdf
www.domain.com/privacy_policy/privacy_policy.doc
www.domain.com/privacy_policy/privacy_policy.rtf
www.domain.com/privacy_policy/privacy_policy.txt
```

and I need to redirect all of them to:

```
www.domain.com/privacy-policy-document
```

Is there any rules which I can safety apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this single rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about/(about)\. /$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(privacy_policy)/privacy_policy\. /$1-document [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my question, so could you please look at it again and provide me with updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine, I just changed [L,NC,R=302] to [L,NC,R=301] to get 301 permanent redirection. I hope everything else is fine now.